# Save stata file as R file

Tags: r, save, stata

I am trying to save the stata file as a R file using the "save command" but repeatedly getting an error:

```
>library(foreign)
# read stata file (there is a stata file "data.dta" in working directory)
>read.dta("data.dta")
  var1       var2     var3       var4       var5
1 -4.239497  0.2406101 3.786384 -1.3025404  0.3428481
2 -3.311914  1.9533381 3.200867 -2.4428566  0.9154460
3 -2.156078  1.6590545 4.317356 -3.1660178  1.6963958
4  2.648022 -1.4091060 3.227258 -0.9857693  1.4566656
>getwd()
"C:/Users/Vista/Documents" 
>save(data.dta, file = "data.rda")
Error in save(data.dta, file = "data.rda") : object 'data.dta' not found
```

Suggestion in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You have to read your stata file first.

Comment: I am still getting the error even after reading the data file. Can you give me an extra hint?

Comment: Can you show the code where you define `data.dta`?

Comment: Andrie: I have updated the code in the question. Please suggest

Comment: You need to assign the data to an R object first `data.dta <- read.dta("data.dta")`

Comment: otherwise it is just printed to your console. you can check which objects are in your workspace by typing `ls()`

Comment: Adibender: Your solution worked perfect. Thanks!

Comment: well, thank @Andrie. also you might want to check out his book :-)

Comment: this is a perfectly reasonable confusion for an R beginner, but also very very basic.  I think perhaps it should be closed as "too localized" -- the problem certainly has nothing directly to do with reading and saving Stata files ...

Comment: I think the best answer would be for @abibender to post as an answer and userXXXXX to accept.

Comment: Thanks @adibender for suggesting the book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the data to an R object first, otherwise the read in data is just printed to your console but not available in your workspace:

```
 data.dta <- read.dta("data.dta")
 save(data.dta, file = "data.rda")
```

If you want to check which objects are available in your workspace, you can type `ls()`.

On a side note: You might want to consider saving the object in the `.Rds` format via

```
saveRDS(data.dta, file = "data.Rds")
```

instead of using `save` and saving it in the `.rda` format. When you load the data via `load("data.rda")` the object will still have the (maybe confusing) name data.dta. When you save it as `.Rds` you can rename it upon loading/reading it, e.g.

```
anyname <- readRDS("data.Rds")
```

Comment: as requested by @DWin, a proper answer...